# does windows xp sound driver work on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers, audio

So my question is does Windows 7 sound driver work on Windows xp and in vice versa too? beside this, how about in terms 32,64 bits of both operating system?

Please, I need this answer in 2 days. 
at least help me by posting a link so that I can read from a website.

Answer (score 3):

The two operating systems use a different driver model so the Windows 7 driver won't work on Windows XP or vice versa.

The same applies to 32bit vs 64 bit - if you have a 64 bit OS you need a 64 bit driver and for the 32 bit OS a 32 bit driver.

Comment: Can I please have details?

Comment: @yetnayet - all I'd do is use Google to find out more - I'm an application developer, not a driver developer so I don't know the details, but I'm sure that a search for "Windows XP driver model" or "Windows 7 driver model" would yield some useful information.

Comment: The details are quite technical, but in the following post a MS employee explains why they changed the driver model in Vista (Windows 7 use more or less the same model): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iliast/archive/2006/10/04/introduction-to-the-windows-driver-model-_2800_wdm_2900_.aspx. Search "Windows Driver Foundation" for details about the new model.

Comment: Thank you for details. But I would like make my question clear here. My teacher asked me to Blog or Research in details if Windows XP sound driver works for Windows 7 too in vice versa as well. And in addition he asked me to explain why even if it works or not.

Comment: @Yetnayet - I did think that this was a homework question which was partly why I deliberately left out the details.